# Merge two Dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, array-merge

I have a dictionary like this. It's a set of parameters to be set in a HTTP body.

```
let parameters = [ "UserCredentials": [ "Personalnumber": personalNo, "Password": password ], "DeviceCredentials": ["UniqueId": uniqueId] ]
```

The type inference output of the `parameters` variable is `[String : Dictionary<String, String>]`.

What I want to do is instead of creating this dictionary explicitly, I want to *build* it. As in have functions to create each section of it and finally merge them all to have the final output as the original one shown above.

```
func deviceCredentials() -> [String: [String: String]] {
    return ["DeviceCredentials" : ["UniqueId": "1212121212"]]
}

func userCredentials(pnr: String, password: String) -> [String: [[String: String]]] {
    let personalNo = ["Personalnumber": pnr]
    let password = ["Password": password]

    return ["UserCredentials": [personalNo, password]]
}
```

I have two separate methods to create each section.

I don't know how to merge the output from these two because their output types are different.

Comment: There can be multiple ways, one is pre-define your keys in array, loop it, and have a common function which can create values for key using if else condition.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the merger function yourself that will loop through both dictionaries and combine them into one. I think the reason Apple wouldn't provide that function is what if there's a conflict (same key is present in both dictionaries)?

For what you want to do, I think it may be easier to create an NSMutableDictionary and then pass it as a parameter to both functions so that each of them can add the objects it needs to add.

Answer (score 0):

Because your inner-most dictionaries vary in type, you will need to use `AnyObject` when you define your outermost dictionary and downcast when you retrieve the items as necessary.  You can also return a tuple instead of a Dictionary to make it easier to build your outermost dictionary -

```
func deviceCredentials() -> (key:String, value:[String: String]) {
    return ("DeviceCredentials",["UniqueId": "1212121212"])
}

func userCredentials(pnr: String, password: String) -> (key:String, value:[[String: String]]) {
    let personalNo = ["Personalnumber": pnr]
    let password = ["Password": password]

    return ("UserCredentials", [personalNo, password])
}

var dict=Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()

let deviceCreds=deviceCredentials()

dict[deviceCreds.key]=deviceCreds.value

let userCreds=userCredentials("user", "password")

dict[userCreds.key]=userCreds.value
```

However, you can change the structure of your `userCredentials` value slightly and use -

```
func deviceCredentials() -> (key:String, value:[String: String]) {
    return ("DeviceCredentials",["UniqueId": "1212121212"])
}

func userCredentials(pnr: String, password: String) -> (key:String, value:[String: String]) {
    var retDict=Dictionary<String,String>()
    retDict["Personalnumber"] = pnr
    retDict["Password"]= password

    return ("UserCredentials", retDict)
}

var dict=Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>>()

let deviceCreds=deviceCredentials()

dict[deviceCreds.key]=deviceCreds.value

let userCreds=userCredentials("user", "password")

dict[userCreds.key]=userCreds.value
```